# how to use Ajax success function store data in database?Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

I want to get data(user) from dropdown by using Ajax success function. I want when clicking 'add member',it will show username under the button,and also the username will stay when refreshing the page.

```
{% block script %}
    var url = $( '#selection-button' ).attr( 'action' );
    $("#selection-button").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value =$('#member_list').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '{% url 'project:project_add_member' project_id=project_id %}',
            data: { user_id:value },
            success:function (result) {
                $("#res").append(value);
            },
            error:function (result) {
              alert('error');
              console.info(data);
            }
        });
    });

{%  endblock %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just a trick: Firstly, display the username as a result of an Ajax call like you did in a div area. Secondly, you actually have a tag for the username in this area , example: {{username}}.

*At first it's always empty as there is no data in you db (nothing to show), but just after you fill the data, first it will bring the ajax result there, which is temporary but it will go on showing the same data upon your refresh as you always call it via the tag I wrote above.*

You can get this {{username}} tag via your *view*. Hope you know how to call it from DB.

Comment: The data which you mentioned is user? If so, then I have data in my DB. I can get data from DB, but I could not let it stay in my webpage. I am not sure if i should create extra db for storing them, or modify url to display them correctly @demyr

Comment: In your view try:
usern = myModel.objects.filter(user=request.user)
...
return render(request, 'yourFolder/your_template.html', {'usern':usern})

Then in your template use {{usern}} tag to show it anytime!

Comment: what is 'myModel' coming from? @demyr

Comment: It's the name of your model. Please check this title and filter options https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Comment: In this case is User? I did not create a new model for user.   @demyr

Comment: No need to create a new model for User. It is a predefined, automatic model on django. As I said, you should use a queryset to get a data from database and show it in your template with the help of  template tags on django. If you watch some basic videos on youtube, I believe you will easily understand and accomplish this. Just type 'django tutorials' and go!

Comment: I know how to query data from database, but the problem is I do not know how to put these data I query into another dataset and display them even when user refresh the page. I do not think you even understand what i meant @demyr

Comment: Actually, I explained it in my answer dear @Sue-MayXu. You can create another model to keep records for your chosen user lists, then query it in your view (check to see if request.user and added member match) and show the result on the template with a tag name created via your request. No matter how many times you refresh the page as it will query a result (if there is a match) from your view.